# Is it must to follow this Sunnah

Tags: prophet-muhammad, sunnah, muslim-practices

Prophet (PBUH) used to eat on ground by spreading a mat on the ground and I know this is a Sunnah. Is it obligatory to follow this Sunnah or is it Mustahab?
Jazakallah Khair

Comment: Sunnah by default is a recommendation (it is the best way) unless emphasized otherwise. It is however regarded as disrespectful or sinful to refute or reject something that is sunnah: to make clear what I mean to say if somebody told you that the prophet used to do such and such and it is sunnah and could provide a hadith you shouldn't reject it, just because it is sunnah, even if you don't feel like doing so if this was about something he liked to wear or eat as his habits are not a must for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is highly mustahab as the Prophet SAW was an example for us, and we should try to follow his example. His habits are part of the Sunnah, and it is highly recommended but not obligatory that we follow them.